# How do i do NPM install --force on heroku

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

So I have to use `npm i react-google-login --force` to install the google login component into my local machine, I used ci/cd on Heroku connected my GitHub but it is refusing to install the react-google-login component on Heroku. Please how can I use the `npm I react-google-login --force` on Heroku?
This is the error I'm getting below on my deploy.

```
-----> Installing dependencies        
remote:        Installing node modules        
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE        
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve        
remote:        npm ERR!         
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: react-google-login@5.2.2        
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0        
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react        
remote:        npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project        
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17 || ^18" from @headlessui/react@1.6.5        
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@headlessui/react        
remote:        npm ERR!     @headlessui/react@"^1.6.4" from the root project        
remote:        npm ERR!   11 more (@heroicons/react, @testing-library/react, formik, ...)        
remote:        npm ERR!         
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:        
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2        
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login        
remote:        npm ERR!   react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project        
remote:        npm ERR!         
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2        
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react        
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2        
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-login        
remote:        npm ERR!     react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project        
remote:        npm ERR!         
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry        
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps        
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.        
remote:        npm ERR!         
remote:        npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.7FR4A/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.        
remote:                
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:        
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.7FR4A/_logs/2022-07-11T20_31_06_507Z-debug-0.log        
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put this option in your repository's `.npmrc`:

```
force=true
```

Alternatively, to revert back to npm's looser peer dependency checking:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

Comment: But I do not have a `.npmrc` in my project just a workflow.yaml can I create one and where do I place it?

Comment: You can put it at the root of your project